# What state does the entity need to trigger the [update] operation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Version: 1.1.2.RELEASE

I have the following simple test code

```
    JobTask task1 = new JobTask(null, "task1", "sync files", JobStatus.RUNNING);
    JobTask savedTask = jobTaskReponsitory.save(task1);
    savedTask.setTaskDesc("update descript.");
    jobTaskReponsitory.save(savedTask);
```

JobTask aggregate root contains `@Id` `@Version` `@CreatedDate` `@CreatedBy` `@LastModifiedBy` `@LastModifiedDate` annotation.

1. Why is the `InsertRoot` operation always triggered? In the second `save()` operation, the entity already has `ID` Value, and I understand that the `update()` operation should be triggered at this time.
2. Is there documentation available about `@Version`? I didn't find anything official.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question lies in the second.

Optimistic locking/ the `@Version` attribute isn't yet supported by Spring Data JDBC. This is why there is no official documentation about it. [There is a PR request though](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/pull/166).

This also means the version attribute will be unchanged `null` or `0` depending on its type.
But it will be checked for determining if an entity is considered new:
An entity is considered new if the ID is `null` or `0` or if there is a property annotated with `@Version` which is `null` or `0`.

Since the second condition always stays `true` in your case Spring Data JDBC will always perform an `insert`.

To fix the situation I recommend removing the version attribute or at least the `@Version` annotation for now since it is probably without value since optimistic locking isn't implemented anyway.

Comment: So in which version will optimistic locking be implemented? thank you~

Comment: Currently it looks like it might be included in the 2.0 release which is scheduled for the first half of 2020.

Comment: Version 2.0 of Spring Data JDBC will contain support for Optimistic Locking. I just merged the PR into master.